# SSH authentication with an YubiKey 5 + GPG + ED25519

Tags: ssh, openssh, yubikey

I'm using a YubiKey 5 to store my ED25519 private key.

I can connect to an OpenSSH_8.2p1 server (Ubuntu 20.04) but not to an OpenSSH_8.9p1 server (Ubuntu 22.04).
I have the following error:

SSH client :

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519 "/home/emeric/.ssh/id_ed25519" from agent: agent refused operation
```

GPG agent:

```
sept. 03 18:53:46 ndesk gpg-agent[5563]: scdaemon[5563]: app_auth failed: Invalid value
sept. 03 18:53:46 ndesk gpg-agent[5552]: smartcard signing failed: Invalid value
sept. 03 18:53:46 ndesk gpg-agent[5552]: ssh sign request failed: Invalid value <SCD>
```

I have found the same issue here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=274571
But the `KexAlgorithms -sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com` ssh parameter doesn't have any effect for me :(

There are other people in the same situation as me that found a solution?

Thanks,
Emeric

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by resetting the OpenSSH server configuration and host keys…